# Android: Get checked checkbox values

Tags: android

I need to get checked checkbox values when button clicked.
Java Code:

```
dualcamera1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Camera1_DualDisplay);
dualcamera2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Camera2_DualDisplay);
dualcamera3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Camera3_DualDisplay);
dualcamera4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Camera4_DualDisplay);
dualdisplay = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.DisplayDualVideo);
```

Comment: you want to get values of checkbox?you mean,you want to know the status of checkbox,or something else? please explain your requirement bit more.

Comment: I need to select only two checkbox if the user selects single,more than mutiple checkboxes need to display message. Once the button clicked i need to know the checked checkbox values.

Comment: It's still not clear completely.You want to prevent user from selecting more/less then 2 checkboxes? and also,what do you mean by value of checkbox?its checked state or its text?

Comment: User should select only two checkboxes. I need to get checked state.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can call `isChecked()` on a checkbox to get its status. If you want to count the number of checked checkboxes you could store then in an ArrayList and loop through that.

Comment: That's Right ❤️

Answer (score 61):

Its simple:

```
static int m=0;
dualDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnCli....{
     onClick()
     {
          if(dualcamera1.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(dualcamera2.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(dualcamera3.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
          if(dualcamera4.isChecked())
              m++; // you can save this as checked somewhere
     }
});
if(m>2 || m<2)
      // show error message
else
      // code here
```

you can save checkbox's detail if its selected,in if it is checked,in for loop only.

Answer (score 26):

If CheckBox isn't define in onCreate() method then have to use something like this:

```
boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).isChecked()
```

Answer (score 14):

The correct option to get the [Checkbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) value is using the method:

> **isChecked()** The current checked state of the view

```
dualcamera1.isChecked()
```

---

`isEnable()` just return True if this view is enabled, false otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

This may help you:

```
//Returns the enabled status for this view. 
dualcamera1.isEnabled()  //return True if this view is enabled, false otherwise. 

//Indicates whether the view is currently in pressed state.
dualcamera1.isPressed() //return True if this view is enabled, false otherwise.
```