# how to get checked multiple values using custom adapter in android

Tags: android

I have listview with custom adapter. Every element of this listview has checkbox. Standart function `.isChecked()` does not work.

someActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            List<Boolean> listCheck;
            listCheck = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

            for (int i = 0; i < CA_main_trx.editModelArrayList.size(); i++){
                Boolean stat = CA_main_trx.editModelArrayList.get(i).getCheckShare();
                String nilaiPcs = CA_main_trx.editModelArrayList.get(i).getTextView_main_trx2();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: --a" + nilaiPcs);
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: --a" + stat);
            }
        }
    });
```

CustomeAdapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final String TAG = "CA_Main_Trx : ";
...
        holder.checkShare.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    String id = editModelArrayList.get(position).getTextView_main_trx0();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: True"+id);
                }
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: False");
            }

        });
...
```

model

```
package com.m.t;

public class EM_main_trx {

    private boolean checkShare;

    public Boolean getCheckShare() {return checkShare;}

    public void setCheckShare(Boolean checkShare) {
        this.checkShare = checkShare;
    }
}
```

When checked in custome Adapter i get the checked status. But when i get the data using button in my mainactivity i got stuck. just got null.

Some my reference :

- [Android: Get checked checkbox values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411540/android-get-checked-checkbox-values)
- [Finding the Checked state of checkbox in a custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953697/finding-the-checked-state-of-checkbox-in-a-custom-listview)
- [how to get the the multiple checkbox values using custom adapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192850/how-to-get-the-the-multiple-checkbox-values-using-custom-adapter-in-android)
- [Android List View Custom Adapter with Checkbox multiple selection and Search Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385166/android-list-view-custom-adapter-with-checkbox-multiple-selection-and-search-lis)
- [Checked values of CheckBox with Custom Listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910936/checked-values-of-checkbox-with-custom-listview-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update part of custome adapter to this :

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
     editModelArrayList.get(position).setCheckShare(b);
}
```